# How can I change the title of a Fragment without changing the title of the MainActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I would like that in each `Fragment` the title of the `ActionBar` will be adapted. For example, if I select the option "Lists" (that is a `Fragment`), the title of the `ActionBar` have to be "Lists".

I can do it using the following code:

```
getActivity().setTitle("Lists");
```

but when I go back to `MainActivity` (using the menu option or the back button on the mobile phone) it maintains the title "Lists" instead of "My application" that is the default title.

If I try to set the title on `MainActivity`:

```
setTitle("My application");
```

it is not changed.

How can I maintain the title of the `MainActivity` and modify the title in each of the `Fragments`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I am able to modify the title of your `MainActivity` after enter in a `Fragment` and modify the title of the `ActionBar` in it. I needed to change it with two different events: when I click on the menu of the application and when I press back button of the mobile phone. I will separate my answer in two parts, one for each event:

**- To change title on MainActivity when you press back button on your mobile phone**

You need to use `onBackPressed()` method on your `MainActivity.class` to detect the event and then use `setTitle` method to change the title of your `ActionBar`.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    setTitle("Lists");
}
```

**- To change title on MainActivity when you press option "Home" in your menu.**

On your `onNavigationItemSelected` method you can detect when you press the option "Home" and then start a new `Fragment` (let's call it `MainFragment`) which returns an empty layout so if you are in another `Fragment`, for example `AnotherFragment` (with another `ActionBar` title) and you press your "Home" option in your menu you can set again the title of your `MainActivity` as default one in your `MainFragment` with the following code:

```
getActivity().setTitle("Lists");
```

In this way you will be able to change the title of your `MainActivity` maintaining its layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try using getSupportActionBar().setTitle("title");

That's what I use and it seems to work good. Here's an example using my code where I add fragments to a viewpager.

```
private void addPages(ViewPager pager) {
    MyFragPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String workout = intent.getStringExtra("work");
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("work", work);
    String title = args.getString("work");
    switch(title) {
        case "w29w1" : {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Work 29 Week 1");
            break;
        }
        case "w29w2" : {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Work 29 Week 2");
            break;
        }
MondayFragment mondayFragment = new MondayFragment();
    mondayFragment.setArguments(args);
```

In that example, I'm simply setting the title of the toolbar to something, depending on the intent it got from the previous class, as the fragment is used for multiple sets of data.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code on `onResume()` of both activity and Fragment

**Fragment:**

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(getActivity().getSupportActionBar()!=null)
           getActivity().getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Lists");
    }
```

**Activity:**

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(getSupportActionBar()!=null)
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title");
    }
```

Comment: It gives to me the same effect. It changes the `Fragment` title but it maintains the title of the `Fragment` on the `MainActivity` view.

Comment: Override `onBackPressed()` of activity and `setTitle` their for you activity

Comment: I also have tried with `onBackPressed()` but it still does not change the MainActivity title again.

Comment: No, I cannot share all the code but I can share some parts of them. What would be relevant? It has around 1000+ lines my MainActivity.

Comment: That part of code where you setting your toolbar title in Activity and Fragment

Comment: Ok, by the moment I have on `Fragment` in `onCreateView` method: `getActivity().setTitle("Lists");` and now in `MainActivity` class in `onBackPressed` method: `setTitle("My application");`

Comment: Have you used `toolbar` in activity?

Comment: I do not know what exactly you mean with `toolbar` on Android but I am using the default `ActionBar`.

Comment: As of new Google Standards we use `Toolbar` instead of `Actionbar` in activty

Comment: Your refer this [Example](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html)

Comment: Finally I got the solution for both events (click back button on the mobile phone and press "home" button on my menu). I have added an answer with the solution. Thank you very much for your time! :)